# Binding a ViewModel class that contains nested objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist, selectlistitem

I've created a class which holds objects of other complex classes.

So for instance

```
class A {

    public int ID { set; get; }

    public string MyObjectName {set; get; }

    public B ObjectOfTypeB { set; get; }

}

class B {

    public int ID { set; get; }

    public int CategoryNumber { set; get; }

    public string CategoryDescription { set; get; }

}
```

Now I have a controller method which creates objects of type A. I scaffolded a view for creation of my model (class A). But because A holds a complex type it doesn't know how to create the input fields for the B type.

In my create function

```
// helper method to get a list of the possible B objects - 
// this method will eventually query a database. for now just static objects

private List<Category> getBobjects()
{
    List<B> bs = new List<B>();
    bs.Add(new B() { ID = 1, CategoryNumber = 2, CategoryDescription = "Config 1" });
    bs.Add(new B() { ID = 2, CategoryNumber = 3, CategoryDescription = "Config 2" });
    return bs;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // Adding to the view bags the categories to display
    ViewBag.bs = getBobjects();
    return View();
}
```

And in the View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ObjectOfTypeB, 
       new SelectList(ViewBag.bs, "ID", "CategoryDescription"))
```

I assumed that when submit the form, the data from the ObjectOfTypeB would be binded to the post back object of type A. But this isn't happening.

Can anybody explain how I can pass a list of possible values for a particular field to the view and have the postback bind the value onto the returned object?

[Bug Print Screen][1]

Comment: After POST you have to get data and bind to your model again. After submit you will get only id of choosen data.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qbB4H.png

Comment: I think Felipes answer is correct but in your situations you have to set  ViewBag.bs = getBobjects(); in the ActionResult marked with [HttpPost] attribute too.

Answer (score 1):

Your binding is not correct.  If you're trying to fill the `ID` property of your `ObjectOfTypeB` property, then your `DropDownListFor` should bind to `model => model.ObjectOfTypeB.ID`

If you view source, your source should look something like `<select name="ObjectOfTypeB.ID">` if you expect it to auto-fill that property on postback.

In this case I'd probably use a ViewModel (VM) to represetn your model.  You're not REALLY filling out a full object B, as a B contains a category and description related to the ID selected -- in other words, the three properties are bound together and not separately fillable.

I'd do something like:

```
class AViewModel
{
    public int ID {set;get;}

    public string MyObjectName {set; get;}

    public int IDofB { set; get; }
}
```

To make your life easier of translating between A and AViewModel, look at tools like AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill the `ViewBag` again to return the bind to your `View`. You could create a method that fill this ViewBag for you and use it on the get/post methods add/edit as well. Try to keep your `ViewModels` (I like to call as `InputModel`) only with primitive types (`string`, `int`, `double`, `bool`) in other words, change the B complex type to a `int`. Try something like this:

```
private void SetViewBagCombo(int selectedValue = 0)
{
   ViewBag.bs = new SelectList(getBobjects(), "Id", "CategoryDescription", selectedValue);
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
   SetViewBagCombo(); 
   return View();   
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(A input)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // persist it
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }

   SetViewBagCombo(input.B.Id); 
   return View();   
}
```

And in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdOfB, (SelectList)ViewBag.bs, "Select...")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private IList getBobjects()
        {
        List<B> bs = new List<B>();
        bs.Add(new B() { ID = 1, CategoryNumber = 2, 
             CategoryDescription = "Config 1" });
        bs.Add(new B() { ID = 2, CategoryNumber = 3, 
             CategoryDescription = "Config 2" });
        return bs;
        }

    public IList<SelectListItem> GetDropdownlistItems()
    {
        IList<SelectListItem> ilSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        IList objlist = getBobjects();
        foreach (object[] arrobject in objlist)
        {
            SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem();
            selectListItem.Value = arrobject[0].ToString();
            selectListItem.Text = arrobject[1].ToString();
            ilSelectList.Add(selectListItem);
        }

        return ilSelectList;
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        IList<SelectListItem> ilSelectListItems = GetDropdownlistItems();
        ViewBag.bs = ilSelectListItems;
        return View();
    }
```

and in view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("bs", new SelectList(ViewBag.bs, "Text", "Value"))
```

Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: I tried this code. I have some print screens of the error if you can check it out. Seems that it still isn't binding. (notice the names of the classes are not as written above)

Comment: It is because dropdown is not getting the item value except null.  in getCategories() use IList instead of List<Category> and keep the rest in the function as you have written. In GetDropdownlistItems() function write:  IList objlist = getCategories();
        foreach (object[] arrobject in objlist)
        { SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem();
            selectListItem.Value = arrobject[0].ToString();
            selectListItem.Text = arrobject[1].ToString();
            ilSelectList.Add(selectListItem);} and keep return type as you have written.

Answer (score 0):

I created a viewmodel for that complex class type model

had a key for each of the nested objects and for those keys used a selectlist from the referenced object type for the text to display.

After that on the post back I translated the viewmodel back to the type of the model